# WURFL Java API does not identify mobile app user agents correctly

Tags: java, api, user-agent, mobile-application, wurfl

I have used WURFL Java API (also using the web browser patch) to create a standalone application for device detection. When a user agent for mobile app is used , it returns generic web browser (or blank field if web browser patch is not used) for Android and application version as device_os_version for Apple iPhone app user agents. The algorithm used in the new api as described in [new api algorithms](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/newapi/) should give correct results but its not!

Can anyone help me how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used the JavaAPI myself, but I have had good luck so far getting support directly from the WURFL community forums. They have a subforum for API problems. I would suggest making a post there, including the user agent string that's giving you problems and a sampling of the source code you've attempted to use before.

http://www.scientiamobile.com/forum/index.php

Sorry I couldn't give you a direct answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have been following WLMProgramming and scientiamobile forums and it seems that I have two options. Update the patch and include all the unidentified entries manually or create a WURLF Matcher to handle those UAs. I am going to try and create WURFL Matcher and will notify once I get it working.